# How to synchronize the scrolling between two components in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: My app]

I have a really simple app where two components just sit. In the components, there are some texts, and they're scrollable.

I want to use the second one for a better readability; so I want to make it looks as if the texts are enlarged compered to the texts from the first one.

Here is what I want to achieve: when I scroll the second one, then the first one also gets scrolled at the same time.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { ScrollView, View, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        {/* The first one */}
        <ScrollView>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text>This is a text.</Text>
        </ScrollView>

        {/* The second one that's enlarged*/}
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a text.</Text>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a text.</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Is there any way to do that?
Thank you in advance!